# Android back button does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native

My screen should show a spinner util I get a response from the async operation that's running.

**Expected Behavior**
Clicking AndroidBackButton while the loading state is true ... I should jump back to the Home screen, and cancel the current op.

I determine the loading state by a `loading` field I pull up from my redux store ...

```
 handleAndroidBackButton = () => {
    const { loading } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return navigation.navigate('Search', { mode: BLANK, query: '' });
    }
  }
```

**Issue is** `loading` field inside `handleAndroidBackButton` is always false ...

However I tried to console log the value of `loading` in the `render` method, and it turns into false as expected.

handleAndroidBackButton doesn't sound to listen to changes of the component's props correctly ... I don know.

Any help?

Comment: Just update **loading** to false so loader will be remove and then call Actions.pop() to navigate to previous screen and destroy network instances in unmount.